# Why does this for loop repeat infintely

Tags: php, for-loop, web

For some reason if I use a simple counter such as ++ this works fine however using +3 repeats the code infinitely.

```
for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i + 3 ) {

    echo cl_image_tag("property".$i.".jpg", array( "alt" => "Sample Image" ));

                        }
```

Comment: you don't change $i = `$i = $i+3`

Comment: Here `$i + 3` you just add 3 to `$i`, but you don't save it back to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop statement consists of 3 parts:

- The initialization
- The loop-condition
- The iteration-change

The problem with your statement in the change part of the loop is that this statement does not actually change the loop variable (in your case `$i`).

You have to assign the new value to the loop variable.
I.e. like this:

```
for (...;...; $i = $i + 3)
```

or

```
for (...;...; $i += 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$i + 3` does do anything. It's just a statement and doesn't assign the value of `$i + 3` to `$i`. Thus `$i` will equal `1` on the every loop iteration. So it will never be greater or equal to 10.

You need to use `+=` to add 3 to the value of `$i` on each iteration of the loop.

```
for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i += 3 ) {
```

Comment: `$i + 3 overwrites the value of $i each time`  -  are you sure? :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i = $i+3 )` or `for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i+=3 )`, so you save the new value back to the variable

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i += 3 ) {

echo cl_image_tag("property".$i.".jpg", array( "alt" => "Sample Image" ));

                    }
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. You should read, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the code `$i + 3` as with each iteration the `$i` will default to `1` and `$i + 3` makes it `4`. So, the highest value of `$i` will always be `4` before it goes back to `1` again. Instead you need to save it, so that the loop will increment it after each iteration as in:

```
for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i = $i + 3 ) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are only increasing the $i value by 3, but not saving it.

```
for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i=$i + 3 ) {
     echo cl_image_tag("property".$i.".jpg", array( "alt" => "Sample Image" ));
}
```